# What is the `sshd_config` parameter to set the time between password prompts?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

If I attempt a logon with bad credentials to an `sshd` server, I am greeted with `Access denied` after about a 2 second pause.

Is there a way to increase the time it takes to return the password entry prompt?

Note that I already have `LoginGraceTime` set to a value of `20s`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be controlled with the `pam_faildelay.so` PAM module ([man](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_faildelay)).

Under RHEL 6, the following file applies to `sshd`:

**/etc/pam.d/sshd:**

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       optional     pam_faildelay.so delay=[N time in microseconds]
auth       include      password-auth


account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth

password   include      password-auth

# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
```

If you don't want to set the `delay` within the `pam` module config you can set it in:

**/etc/login.defs:**

```
 FAIL_DELAY    [N time in seconds]
```

Note that, oddly, FAIL_DELAY accepts the time in seconds.

To apply this to console logins, modify `/etc/pam.d/password-auth` and/or `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`.  Also note, you must include the `pam_faildelay.so` line BEFORE any other `auth` lines (particularly `pam_unix.so`).